# WP7 What is the link for "rate and review"?

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

When you publish an application on the marketpace, you may access it by link
http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=GUIDOfApplication
which redirects to application's page on the market.
I know that that it is possible to link directly to "rate and review". So, what is that link?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From within your app you can call the `MarketplaceReviewTask`. As far as I know it's not possible to rate and review an application unless you have it installed on your phone.

Obviously until you publish your app to Marketplace this will give an error as the phone  can't find your app in Marketplace.

See [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh394030(v=VS.92).aspx) for more detail.

Comment: OK. Thank you. To avoid an error probably I will have to add this thing in a first update.

Comment: It should be fairly reliable - just beware that the app GUID  will change from the one in WMAppManifest.xml once the application goes through Marketplace.

Comment: You don't have to submit a GUID to show the ReviewTask, it automatically takes the GUID of the current application. So you can savely use it in your very-first version, the user will not get any error because when he use it the app is available in marketplace. You only get an error while developing / testing.