# how to direct a user to rate my app?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to direct my user to rate and review my app. Is there an embedded way or must i send my user to the app page on marketplace website?

I can't remember exactly, but i think i saw somewhere in an app review integrated and can't seem to find anything on MSDN. Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [WP7 What is the link for "rate and review"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7443552/wp7-what-is-the-link-for-rate-and-review)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MarketplaceReviewTask`
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7444337/694641